# Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'items[0].index.error', line 1, position 137

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 2.1  in my dotnet project . The issue m facing as of now is m not able to insert the bulk data getting exception in the below line. 
var result = client.Bulk(bulkInsertData);
Error :
Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'items[0].index.error', line 1, position 137.

StackTrace :
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Nest.Resolvers.Converters.BulkOperationResponseItemConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeUsingSettings[T](Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.StreamToTypedResponse[T](ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ITransportRequestState requestState, Byte[] readBytes)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.ReturnTypedResponse[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ElasticsearchServerError& error)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.Request[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Object data)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.Bulk[T](Object body, Func`2 requestParameters)
   at Nest.RawDispatch.BulkDispatch[T](ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 pathInfo, Object body)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.b__339_0(ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 p, IBulkRequest d)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Nest.IHighLevelToLowLevelDispatcher.Dispatch[D,Q,R](D descriptor, Func`3 dispatch)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Bulk(IBulkRequest bulkRequest)
   at ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchInsertData.InsertCaseData() in ElasticSearch.cs:line 61

By running the below code: Mapping gets created and data will not be inserted as m getting the above mentioned error Mapping that has been created with 0 documents 
GET /1246Index pap/_mapping

```
   "1246Index&nbsp;pap": {
  "mappings": {
     "ElasticSearchInfo": {
        "properties": {
           "Number": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
           },
            "ID": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
           },
           "Type": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "NestedObjectinformation": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "Name": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}

CODE :

```
[ElasticType(Name = "ElasticSearchInfo")]
public class ElasticSearchNestedInfo
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "ID", Index = FieldIndexOption.No, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "Type", Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "Number", Index = FieldIndexOption.No, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "nestedobjectinformation", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.Nested)]
    public List<ElasticSearchNestedInfo> NestedObjectinformation { get; set; }
}

[ElasticType(Name = "ElasticSearchNestedInfo")]
public class ElasticSearchNestedInfo
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "Name", Index = FieldIndexOption.No, Type = FieldType.String)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


List<ElasticSearchInfo> elasticSearchCaseInfo = caseBL.GetElasticSearchInsertData(i);
        string connElasticServer = SystemCacheHelper.GetElasticSearchConnectionString();
        var node = new Uri(connElasticServer);

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).ExposeRawResponse();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        BulkDescriptor bulkInsertData = new BulkDescriptor();

        foreach (var item in elasticSearchCaseInfo)
        {
            string index = item.ID + item.Type; 

            client.CreateIndex(ind => ind.Index(index).AddMapping<ElasticSearchInfo>(map => map.MapFromAttributes()));
             // .AddMapping<ElasticSearchNestedInfo>(diag => diag.MapFromAttributes()));

            bulkInsertData.Index<ElasticSearchInfo>(bulkInsert => bulkInsert.Document(item)
               .Index(index)
                    .Type(item.Type)
                        .Id((item.ID)));
        }

        if (elasticSearchCaseInfo.Count > 0)
        {
            var result = client.Bulk(bulkInsertData);


           client.Map<ElasticSearchInfo>(m => m
                        .MapFromAttributes()
                        .Properties(p => p
                        .NestedObject<ElasticSearchNestedInfo>(no => no
                            .Name(n => n.NestedObjectinformation.First())
                            .Dynamic()
                            .Enabled()
                            .IncludeInAll()
                            .IncludeInParent()
                            .IncludeInRoot()
                            .MapFromAttributes()
                            .Path("nestedobjectinformation")
                            )
                            )
                            );
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually trying to put each document in a separate index? That kinda discard idea of BULK inserting.

Comment: Yes m trying to create index for each document. This was working fine when mapping was done at the parent level. 
client.Map<ElasticSearchInfo>(m => m.MapFromAttributes());
Since search for nested object was not working i tried mapping to nested object . Then on i started to get the above error

Comment: In such case you don't need bul operations at all.

Answer (score 0):

Under assumption that your intention was to create index and put there content of list with single bulk insert. You should do something like this:

```
public void TestBulkInsert()
        {
            List<ElasticSearchInfo> elasticSearchCaseInfo = caseBL.GetElasticSearchInsertData(i);
            string connElasticServer = SystemCacheHelper.GetElasticSearchConnectionString();
            var node = new Uri(connElasticServer);

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).ExposeRawResponse();
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            client.CreateIndex(_ => _.Index<ElasticSearchInfo>()));
            client.Map<ElasticSearchInfo>(
                m => m
                    .Index<ElasticSearchInfo>()
                    .MapFromAttributes()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .NestedObject<ElasticSearchNestedInfo>(no => no
                            .Name(n => n.NestedObjectinformation.First())
                            .Dynamic()
                            .Enabled()
                            .IncludeInAll()
                            .IncludeInParent()
                            .IncludeInRoot()
                            .MapFromAttributes()
                            .Path("nestedobjectinformation")
                        )
                    )
                );
            var index = client.Infer.IndexName<ElasticSearchInfo>();
            var type = client.Infer.TypeName<ElasticSearchInfo>();
            client.Bulk(
                bd => elasticSearchCaseInfo.Aggregate(
                    bd,
                    (bdi, item) => bdi
                        .Index<ElasticSearchInfo>(
                            bid => bid
                                .Index(index)
                                .Type(type)
                                .Id(item.ID)
                                .Document(item)
                        )
                    )
                );
        }
```

Also I strongly advise you to not use mapping by attributes or at least dont mix it with fluent mapping.

Comment: Tried with the above code. Getting exception while creating index.         Could not dispatch IElasticClient.IndicesCreate() into any of the following paths:   - /{index}

Comment: Works fine for me also you could use overload with string index name.